# Set Rackspace CloudServer Metadata with pyrax

Tags: python, rackspace-cloud, pyrax

I'm looking at using Rackspace for our server hosting and I need to be able to gain a list of servers based on tag via the API. I've seen other threads on here that its currently not returned in the API, but we can inspect the metadata of a server in order to achieve the same goal.

The problem however is that pyrax doesn't seem to have an option to set the metadata of a cloudserver that already exists, have I missed something or could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following calls:

```
pyrax.cloudservers.servers.delete_meta(server, list_of_keys)
pyrax.cloudservers.servers.set_meta(server, key_value_dict)
```

Be careful of the set_meta call, as set_meta overwrites all metadata.